# Solidity libraries "using A for B"

Tags: solidity, storage, libraries

Concerning the usage of Solidity libraries, is there a difference between using:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract Random {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint256 a = 5;
    uint256 b = 6;

    function addNumbers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return a.add(b);
    }
}
```

vs

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract Random2 {
    uint256 a = 5;
    uint256 b = 6;
    
    function addNumbers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return SafeMath.add(a, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These two achieve the same result but use different approaches. I compared gas efficiencies or both and came to conclusions:

Random costs 162612gas to **deploy**, whereas Random2 costs 160371 gas (**R2 is 2241gas cheaper**).
When it comes to the **addNumbers** function, Random's costs 29419 and Random2's 29401 (**R2 is 18gas cheaper**).

To sum it up, I would in any case recommend using, since then you don't need to worry about using the correct function.

Other than that Random2 would in this case be efficient after the 125th call.